# How to find a view in a class extended from Fragment?

Tags: android

How to find a `view` in a `class` extended from `Fragment` or `ListFragment`? If I try

`Button newItemBtn = (Button)getView().findViewById(R.id.bt_add_item);`

I do not receive my view back, meaning it was just not found. How to find it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer is that you have to do it in `onActivityCreated()` method, not in `onCreate()`.

Answer (score 4):

[android fragment docs](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/fragments.html) states :

```
 View listView = getActivity().findViewById(R.id.list);
```

Comment: Right but that doesn't help without the first one.